# Deploying SpringBoot Project to WLS, Dynamic Web Module keeps reverting back to 4.0

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I have a springboot project that I am working on. I am using spring boot version 2.1.3. I need this version so that I can use mysql connector version 8.0.15. I am using Hibernate and JPA in this project.

Since WLS 12.1.3 does not use servlet 4.0 I am getting this error

When I deploy my .war file to Web Logic Server I get this error:

```
Message icon - Error VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND C:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\dev_domain\weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@2ad4423 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@3be64d51 annotation: \WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.16.jar!\META-INF\web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

I have tried going into org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and setting the dynamic web module in there to 3.1 . However as soon as I update the maven project it reverts back to 4.0.

I have also made changes to my pom file to make sure the right java-x servlet has been used. 
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootJpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootJpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>




</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet specs 4.0 are part of JEE 8 and is not yet implemented in WebLogic Server 12c. You may use another application server that supports JEE 8 and Servlets 4.0.